# Create a subset of a DataFrame depending on column name

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame called `timedata` with different column names, some of which contain the word Vibration, some eccentricity. Is is possible to create a dataframe of just the columns containing the word Vibration?

I have tried using

```
vib=[]
for i in timedata:
    if 'Vibration' in i:
        vib=vib.append(i)
```

to then create a DataFrame based on the indicies of these columns. This really does not seem like the most efficient way to do it and I'm sure there must be something simple to do with list comprehension.

**EDIT**

Dataframe of form:

```
df = DataFrame({'Ch 1:Load': randn(10), 'Ch 2:Vibration Brg 1T ': randn(10), 'Ch 3:Eccentricity Brg 1H ': randn(10), 'Ch 4:Vibration Brg 2T ': randn(10)})
```

Sorry I'm having a slow day! thanks for any help

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Something like this to manually select all columns with the word "Vibration" in it:

```
df[[col for col in df.columns if "Vibration" in col]]
```

You can also do the same with the `filter` method:

```
df.filter(like="Vibration")
```

If you want to do a more flexible filter, you can use the `regex` option. E.g. to look if "Vibration" or "Ecc" is in the column name:

```
df.filter(regex='Ecc|Vibration')
```

Comment: filter works perfectly for what I need. Thanks alot. Sorry I can't upvote because my rep is too low

Comment: is it possible to do something like df.filter(like='Ecc' or 'Vibration')? I tried this and it didnt work

Comment: Added the regex option?

Answer (score 3):

```
 newDf    = Df.loc[:,['Vibration']]
```

or

```
newDf    = Df.loc[:,['Vibration','eccentricity']]
```

to get more collumns

to search for a value in a collumn:

```
newDf    =  Df[Df["CollumnName"] == "vibration"]
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make myself clear, the Column names do not just include the word 'Vibration'. e.g. they are in the form 'Ch 2: Vibration Brg 6T'

Comment: I get the error KeyError: "[['Vibration']] are not in ALL in the [columns]". Thanks for the quick reply though

Comment: Updated my answer, to what I think you need. Please update your original post to show your DataFrame layout.

Comment: Have added to the answer, hope this explains it better