# Find column whose name contains a specific string

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with column names, and I want to find the one that contains a certain string, but does not exactly match it. I'm searching for `'spike'` in column names like `'spike-2'`, `'hey spike'`, `'spiked-in'` (the `'spike'` part is always continuous).

I want the column name to be returned as a string or a variable, so I access the column later with `df['name']` or `df[name]` as normal. I've tried to find ways to do this, to no avail. Any tips?

Answer (score 412, accepted):

Just iterate over `DataFrame.columns`, now this is an example in which you will end up with a list of column names that match:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'spike-2': [1,2,3], 'hey spke': [4,5,6], 'spiked-in': [7,8,9], 'no': [10,11,12]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

spike_cols = [col for col in df.columns if 'spike' in col]
print(list(df.columns))
print(spike_cols)
```

Output:

```
['hey spke', 'no', 'spike-2', 'spiked-in']
['spike-2', 'spiked-in']
```

Explanation:

1. `df.columns` returns a list of column names
2. `[col for col in df.columns if 'spike' in col]` iterates over the list `df.columns` with the variable `col` and adds it to the resulting list if `col` contains `'spike'`. This syntax is [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

If you only want the resulting data set with the columns that match you can do this:

```
df2 = df.filter(regex='spike')
print(df2)
```

Output:

```
   spike-2  spiked-in
0        1          7
1        2          8
2        3          9
```

Comment: That's awesome! I don't really understand exactly how it works, though, still being new to both Python and Pandas. Could you perhaps explain?

Comment: this is what ``DataFrame.filter`` does FYI (and you can supply a regex if you want)

Comment: @xndrme how would you do a regex to **exclude** a certain column matching a regex instead of include?

Comment: @DhruvGhulati You can do this: `spike_cols = [col for col in df.columns if not 'spike' in col]` to get the list of columns that **do not match**, or you can use a lookahead negative regex like `df2 = df.filter(regex='^(?!.*spike).*$')`. Of course this will always depends of the complexity of your excluding patter. You can read more here  https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#lookahead-assertions

Comment: @DhruvGhulati It is possible also to drop your unwanted columns as in `df[df.columns.drop(spike_cols)]`, there you get a `DataFrame` without the columns in the list `spike_cols` which you can obtain using your undesired regex.

Comment: more concise code: `````df[[col for col in df.columns if "spike" in col]]`````

Comment: what if I have a list of strings like `['spike', 'foo', 'bar']` ad want all the columns that contain any of those strings?

Comment: @JacoSolari `[col for col in df.columns if any(s in col for s in ['spike', 'foo', 'bar'])]` or `df.filter(regex='(spike)|(foo)|(bar)')`

Answer (score 143):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20903553) uses the DataFrame.filter method to do this without list comprehension:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'spike-2': [1,2,3], 'hey spke': [4,5,6]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df.filter(like='spike').columns)
```

Will output just 'spike-2'.  You can also use regex, as some people suggested in comments above:

```
print(df.filter(regex='spike|spke').columns)
```

Will output both columns: ['spike-2', 'hey spke']

Comment: I have many columns and I used this code, it seems it skips some of the names! In this example, imagine running this code and not returning 'hey spke' column!!

Comment: How about excluding some columns by name? How would we go about doing that?

Comment: You could do a negative lookahead (regex='^(?!spke)') or get a boolean vector for columns doing something like df.columns.str.contains('spke').

Answer (score 48):

You can also use `df.columns[df.columns.str.contains(pat = 'spike')]`

```
data = {'spike-2': [1,2,3], 'hey spke': [4,5,6], 'spiked-in': [7,8,9], 'no': [10,11,12]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

colNames = df.columns[df.columns.str.contains(pat = 'spike')] 

print(colNames)
```

This will output the column names: `'spike-2', 'spiked-in'`

More about [pandas.Series.str.contains](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html).

Answer (score 42):

```
# select columns containing 'spike'
df.filter(like='spike', axis=1)
```

You can also select by name, regular expression. Refer to: [pandas.DataFrame.filter](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html)

Comment: Easiest solution so far. Simple yet powerful!

Comment: This is a wrong answer. Please note, questions ask for returning 'columns name' with a given string in it or pattern e.g. `spike`.

Answer (score 17):

```
df.loc[:,df.columns.str.contains("spike")]
```

Comment: While it does not exactly answer the original question, I really like this solution as it directly returns the sliced DataFrame (which is actually also what probably the OP is after).

Answer (score 11):

Another solution that returns a subset of the df with the desired columns:

```
df[df.columns[df.columns.str.contains("spike|spke")]]
```

Comment: Does '&' operator work the same way '|' operator works in Regex?

Answer (score 4):

You also can use this code:

```
spike_cols =[x for x in df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('spike')]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Getting name and subsetting based on Start, Contains, and Ends:

```
# from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21285380/find-column-whose-name-contains-a-specific-string
# from: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html
# from: https://cmdlinetips.com/2019/04/how-to-select-columns-using-prefix-suffix-of-column-names-in-pandas/
# from: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html




import pandas as pd



data = {'spike_starts': [1,2,3], 'ends_spike_starts': [4,5,6], 'ends_spike': [7,8,9], 'not': [10,11,12]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)



print("\n")
print("----------------------------------------")
colNames_contains = df.columns[df.columns.str.contains(pat = 'spike')].tolist() 
print("Contains")
print(colNames_contains)



print("\n")
print("----------------------------------------")
colNames_starts = df.columns[df.columns.str.contains(pat = '^spike')].tolist() 
print("Starts")
print(colNames_starts)



print("\n")
print("----------------------------------------")
colNames_ends = df.columns[df.columns.str.contains(pat = 'spike$')].tolist() 
print("Ends")
print(colNames_ends)



print("\n")
print("----------------------------------------")
df_subset_start = df.filter(regex='^spike',axis=1)
print("Starts")
print(df_subset_start)



print("\n")
print("----------------------------------------")
df_subset_contains = df.filter(regex='spike',axis=1)
print("Contains")
print(df_subset_contains)



print("\n")
print("----------------------------------------")
df_subset_ends = df.filter(regex='spike$',axis=1)
print("Ends")
print(df_subset_ends)
```