# How to filter dataframe in pandas by 'str' in columns name?

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, filter, dataframe

Following [this recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21285380/pandas-find-column-whose-name-contains-a-specific-string). I tried to filter a dataframe by the columns name that contain the string '+'. Here's the example:

```
B = pd.DataFrame([[1, 5, 2], [2, 4, 4], [3, 3, 1], [4, 2, 2], [5, 1, 4]],
                columns=['A', '+B', '+C'], index=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

So I want a dataframe C with only '+B' and '+C' columns in it.

```
C = B.filter(regex='+')
```

However I get the error:

```
File "c:\users\hernan\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1888, in filter
matcher = re.compile(regex)
File "c:\users\hernan\anaconda\lib\re.py", line 190, in compile
return _compile(pattern, flags)
File "c:\users\hernan\anaconda\lib\re.py", line 244, in _compile
raise error, v # invalid expression
error: nothing to repeat
```

The recipe says it is Python 3. I use python 2.7. However, I don't think that is the problem here.

Hernan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`+` has a special meaning in regular expressions (see [here](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/re.html)).  You can escape it with `\`:

```
>>> C = B.filter(regex='\+')
>>> C
   +B  +C
1   5   2
2   4   4
3   3   1
4   2   2
5   1   4
```

Or, since all you care about is the presence of `+`, you could use the `like` argument instead:

```
>>> C = B.filter(like="+")
>>> C
   +B  +C
1   5   2
2   4   4
3   3   1
4   2   2
5   1   4
```

Comment: Thanks!. Related, is it possible to do something like C = B.filter(like="+" or like="-")?

Comment: @hernanavella: not with `like`, but you could use `regex`, something like `B.filter(regex="\+|-")` (where the `|` means "or").  But frankly at that point I wouldn't bother trying to be clever, and I'd simply write `B[[col for col in B if "+" in col or "-" in col]]`.