# python: How to select dataframe column by names if it matches more than one substring

Tags: python, regex, dataframe

This is related but diff from another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21285380/pandas-find-column-whose-name-contains-a-specific-string)

```
data = {'spike-2': [1,2,3], 'hey spke': [4,5,6], 'spiked-in': [7,8,9], 'no': [10,11,12]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I want to choose columns by names if column name matches MORE than one substring criteria.

I tried to use AND operator ie &

```
spike_cols = [col for col in df.columns if ('spike') & ('hey') in col]
```

so that I can precisely get the one column 'hey spike'
I also used

```
dfnew = df.filter(regex='spike'&'hey')
```

getting error

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'str'

Comment: Sorry are you after: `df.loc[:,df.columns.str.contains('spike|hey')]`? or in fact: `df.filter(regex='spike|hey')`?

Comment: @EdChum wasnt quite looking for an OR there were many solutions for OR. was looking for an AND condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a method without *regex*, just use `in` to check substring criteria:

```
df[[col for col in df.columns if 'hey' in col and 'spike' in col]]
```

[image]

Or if you want to use *regex*, you can do:

```
df.filter(regex='(?=.*hey)(?=.*spike)')
```

[See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469913/regular-expressions-is-there-an-and-operator).

[image]

Comment: thank you, my first stack question. I also used your answer to modify it to use variables within regex. like df.filter(regex='(?=.*'+a+')(?=.*'+b+')')