# Filter DataFrame columns with regex

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I count statistics for the dataset, and I want to filter columns that contain specific strings. How I could do it with regex?

Here in `volumes_c` I filtered some structures, that have Volume in there names

```
Select_list = ["Amygdala", "Hippocampus", "Lateral-Ventricle", "Pallidum", "Putamen", "Thalamus", "Caudate"]
Side = ["Left", "Right"]
#Selected columns
if(Select_list):
    for s in Side:
        for struct in Select_list:
            volumes_c = group_c.filter(regex="^(?=.*"+s+")(?=.*"+struct+")(?=.*Volume)")
```

Now i want to filter columns that contain `SurfArea` in:

[image: SurfArea]

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21285380/find-column-whose-name-contains-a-specific-string

Answer (score 1):

Suppose DataFrame data is in the variable *df*, so the filter will be:

```
 df.filter(like="SurfArea", axis=1)
```

Actually, 'axis' arg has a default value 1 and you can omit it, but if you want to filter by rows set it up as 0.