# pandas dataframe - does filtering / selecting cols by String preserve order?

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, contains

I have a use case where I have say 10 cols out of which 5 start with the string 'Region'. I need to get a resulting dataframe which only contains those cols (starting with string 'Region'). Not only that, I need to make sure the order is preserved (e.g. if in original df, the col order is `'Region 1', 'Region 2', 'Region 3'` -- this should be preserved and not result in `'Region 3', 'Region 2', 'Region 1'` instead).

Would following the 'accepted answer' for this question preserve the order or is there some other method to achieve that?

[stackoverflow - find-column-whose-name-contains-a-specific-string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21285380/find-column-whose-name-contains-a-specific-string)

Comment: what is in the remaining columns, are they all alpha or alphanumeric?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two steps first use `filter`

```
s=df.filter(like='Region')
```

Comment: I am not sure that this is the answer author requires

Comment: @ArtyomAkselrod this does exactly the same thing as your answer. Maybe replace `like` with `regext='^Region'` is better reflect *startswith*.

Comment: Thanks @Quang Hoang

Comment: @QuangHoang this was a comment to first unedited version and it was incorrect. Now the aswer is correct

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it will. `df.columns` is a list, when you iterate over list, you preserve the order of the list. Thus, you can use the answer from the mentioned link:

```
region_cols = [col for col in df.columns if 'Region' in col]
```

`df[region_cols]` - will be the df you require.

Answer (score 1):

if your data frame is similar to :

```
print(df)


   Region 3  Region 2  Region 1  Custom  UnwantedCol
0         0         0         0       0            0
```

we can use the `sorted` method to sort your columns by the number:

```
nat_cols_sort = dict(sorted(
    {col: int(col.split(" ")[1]) for col in df.filter(regex='^Region').columns}.items(),
    key=lambda x: x[1],
))


print(df[nat_sort.keys()])

   Region 1  Region 2  Region 3
0         0         0         0
```