# sum up row-values over multiple columns into new column in pandas df

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a dataframe (questDay1Df) where I want to sum up the values per row of 21 columns into a new column (BDI_SUM)

I know how to do it by calling and adding each column-value:

```
questDay1Df['BDI_SUM'] = questDay1Df['BD01']+questDay1Df['BD02']+questDay1Df['BD03']+questDay1Df['BD04']+questDay1Df['BD05']+questDay1Df['BD06']+questDay1Df['BD07']+questDay1Df['BD08']+questDay1Df['BD09']+questDay1Df['BD10']+questDay1Df['BD11']+questDay1Df['BD12']+questDay1Df['BD13']+questDay1Df['BD14']+questDay1Df['BD15']+questDay1Df['BD16']+questDay1Df['BD17']+questDay1Df['BD18']+questDay1Df['BD19']+questDay1Df['BD20']+questDay1Df['BD21']
```

Is there a quicker way in which I wouldn't have to write down each column name? BD01-BD21 are all next to each other in the data frame. My idea was to call the column number of BD01 because I am not too sure of it's number and then just write a code to sum up the row-values for this column and the next 20 columns but I wasn't able to implement that now.

TIA for any ideas :)

Comment: `filter()` will work here `df.filter(like='BD').sum(axis=1)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find column whose name contains a specific string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21285380/find-column-whose-name-contains-a-specific-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, use `df.sum` along axis 1 (column wise):

```
questDay1Df['BDI_SUM'] = questDay1Df.sum(axis=1)
```

If you need to filter columns:

```
questDay1Df['BDI_SUM'] = questDay1Df.filter(regex='BD\d+$').sum(axis=1)
```

You can use `like` too in `filter`: `.filter(like='BD')`