# Search for string in column name and return the entire colum

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Is there a way to search for a string or substring in the column name and extract the entire column which name contains that particular string?

My data:

[image]

I want to search for "total" in the data frame and extract the entire column (the last column in this case)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you want to search in column names?

Comment: hint: `df.columns` returns the list of columns in your df

Comment: @MykolaZotko Yes. But there can be multiple keywords like "amount, total, balance" etc

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find column whose name contains a specific string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21285380/find-column-whose-name-contains-a-specific-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are searching for keywords like `Total`, explicitly in column names, use the following:

For this dummy data:

```bash
Description,Qty,Unit Cost (AED), Total Cost (AED), Amount (xyz)
string 1, 3, 3000, 9000, 9500
string 1, 3, 3000, 9000, 9500
string 1, 3, 3000, 9000, 9500
string 1, 3, 3000, 9000, 9500
string 1, 3, 3000, 9000, 9500
string 1, 3, 3000, 9000, 9500
```

Try the following code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import re

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
print(df)

col = [name for name in df.columns if len(re.findall(r'\b(?:total|amount)\b', name.lower()))!=0]

if len(col)!=0:
    print(df.loc[:, col])
```

Comment: assuming, only one of the column names has the word 'Total' in it!

Comment: This code looks for an exact match, while I want to make the code work for even a substring like "total" in the above dataframe

Comment: I made some edits, see if that serves the purpose! made the `name` in lower case, and search for `total`

Comment: It throws an ```IndexError``` because ```.iloc``` requires numerical index but it got ```total```. I've explained my entire problem in the comments above. @anurag

Comment: let me check the problem

Comment: @M_Arora, plz verify if the updated code works for you!

Comment: Yes, perfectly. Thank you so much @anurag

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227630/discussion-between-m-arora-and-anurag).

Answer (score 0):

You can try [str.contains](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) -

```
>>> total_mask = df['Description'].str.contains('total|Total')
>>> total_mask
0     True
1    False
2     True
Name: Description, dtype: bool

>>> df.loc[total_mask,:]
          Description  Total Cost (AED)
0  Compensation Total             100.0
2        Total Amount              20.0
```