# Find column name containing a string after a punctuation

Tags: python-3.x, match

I have a similar question to [Find column whose name contains a specific string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21285380/find-column-whose-name-contains-a-specific-string) but with an extension.

I have a dataframe with column names, and I want to find the ones that contains a certain string, after the underscore symbol.

E.g I'm searching for mango in column names like 'mango_man', 'man_mango', 'apple_mango' but only when it occurs after '_'. Results in this case will only return 'man_mango', 'apple_mango'

Column name to be returned as a string or a variable.

Comment: so you are searching for `_mango` ?

Comment: have you tried `your_list = [word for word in df.columns if '_mango' in word]` where `df` would be your dataframe ofc

Comment: @BijayRegmi, nice way to put it but I want to search for mango after the punctuation because _ occurs in several forms in the data and I want the flexibility to specify the forms.

Comment: And if you want to only return list of results including `mango` after the underscore, and you are not satisfied with command above, you can always do `mango_list = [word for word in my_words if word.split("_")[1] == "mango"]`

Comment: That answers my question, if you put it as a proper answer I will accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For getting list of results containing `mango` after an underscore `_` in your dataframe `df`, you can either do

```
mango_list = [word for word in df.columns if '_mango' in word]
```

or

```
mango_list = [word for word in df.columns if word.split("_")[1]=="mango"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give this to find out if mango_ or _mango exists in the columns.

This will check for both before and after. If you want to check explicitly for after, then you can give `if '_mango' in col`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,(3,7)),
                columns = ['man','man_mango','mango_man','mango','mangoman','manmango','man mango'])
print (df)
mango_cols = [col for col in df.columns if any(x in col for x in ['mango_','_mango'])]
print (mango_cols)
```

The output of this will be:

```
['man_mango', 'mango_man']
```

To get explicitly only values after `_mango`, you can give:

```
cols = [col for col in df.columns if '_mango' in col]
```

The output of this will be:

```
['man_mango']
```