# creating list from dataframe where column name contains particular string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I referred to the solution here - [Find column whose name contains a specific string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21285380/find-column-whose-name-contains-a-specific-string)

```py
spike_cols = [col for col in df.columns if 'spike' in col]
```

However, I want to search for multiple strings at once. For example, I tried to search for string 'keyword' by implementing -

```py
spike_cols = [col for col in df.columns if 'spike | keyword' in col]
```

This doesn't return the list I desire. Any pointers on how to proceed ?

Comment: Like this `if col in {word1, word2, ... wordn}`?

Answer (score 0):

Also possible:

```
# create list for words
words = ['spike', 'keyword']

# store col names in list
cols = list(df.columns)

# list comprehension to return idxs for matches
idx_matches = [i for i in range(len(cols)) if cols[i] in words]

# access the df cols
df.iloc[:, idx_matches]
```