# Python DataFrame add a new columns based on multiple columns condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

I would like to add a new column called XXX based on the last letter in the "indicator" column if:

indicator ends with an S -> Use the value from 'Vendor 5 Ask Price XXX'

indicator ends with an B -> Use the value from 'Vendor 5 Bid Price XXX'

so the new column would be : XXX : [100,nan,107,103]

```
df = {'indicator': ['45346B','24536S','34636S','657363B'],
'Vendor 5 Bid Price XXX' : [100,None,102,103],
'Vendor 5 Ask Price XXX' : [105,None,107,108]}

pd.DataFrame(df)

  indicator  Vendor 5 Bid Price XXX  Vendor 5 Ask Price XXX
0    45346B                   100.0                   105.0
1    24536S                     NaN                     NaN
2    34636S                   102.0                   107.0
3   657363B                   103.0                   108.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about

```py
df[‘XXX’] = df.apply(
    lambda row: row[‘Vendor 5 Ask Price XXX’] if row[‘indicator’].ends with(‘S’) else row[‘Vendor 5 Bid Price XXX’],
    axis=1
)
```

`.apply(…, axis=1)` will apply the function to every row. The lambda function is just the implementation of the switch logic you mentioned and can be more complex if needed.

Comment: thank you, I wasn't clear enough, instead of row[‘Vendor 5 Ask Price XXX’] I would like it to pick the column containing the word "Ask" in the header if row['indicator'].end with('S') else row containing "Bid" in the header.

Comment: You're welcome!
Oh, I see! Then, you should just update the function that is being applied to get the column with the correct value. Here is an example you can adapt to do that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21285380/find-column-whose-name-contains-a-specific-string Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the `indicator` column only ends in `B` or `S`, you can use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html), using the `Bid Price` if the indicator ends with `B`, otherwise the `Ask Price`:

```py
df['XXX'] = np.where(df['indicator'].str.endswith('B'), df['Vendor 5 Bid Price XXX'], df['Vendor 5 Ask Price XXX'])
```

Output:

```
  indicator  Vendor 5 Bid Price XXX  Vendor 5 Ask Price XXX    XXX
0    45346B                   100.0                   105.0  100.0
1    24536S                     NaN                     NaN    NaN
2    34636S                   102.0                   107.0  107.0
3   657363B                   103.0                   108.0  103.0
```