# How to multiply specific column from dataframe with one specific column in same dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, multiple-columns, calculated-columns

I have a dataframe where i need to create new column based on the multiplication of other column with specific column

Here is how my data frame looks.

df:

```
Brand     Price      S_Value        S_Factor
A         10          2             2
B         20          4             1
C         30          2             1
D         40          1             2
E         50          1             1
F         10          1             1
```

I would like multiply column Value and Factor with Price to get new column. I can do it manually but I have a lot of column and all start with specific prefix wihivh i need to multiply... here I used `S_` which mean I need to multiply all the columns which start with `S_`

Here would be te desired output columns

```
Brand     Price      S_Value        S_Factor       S_Value_New       S_Factor_New
A         10          2             2
B         20          4             1
C         30          2             1
D         40          1             2
E         50          1             1
F         10          1             1
```

Comment: Further Reading: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27275236/pandas-best-way-to-select-all-columns-whose-names-start-with-x , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14059094/i-want-to-multiply-two-columns-in-a-pandas-dataframe-and-add-the-result-into-a-n

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, to get the columns which you have to multiply, you can use list comprehension and string function `startswith`. And then just loop over the columns and create new columns by muptiplying with `Price`

```
multiply_cols = [col for col in df.columns if col.startswith('S_')]
for col in multiply_cols:
    df[col+'_New'] = df[col] * df['Price']

df
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since you did not added and example of the output. This might be what you are looking for:

```
dfr = pd.DataFrame({
    'Brand' : ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'], 
    'price'  : [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 10],
    'S_Value'  : [2,4,2,1,1,1],
    'S_Factor'  : [2,1,1,2,1,1]
})

pre_fixes = ['S_']
for prefix in pre_fixes:
    coltocal = [col for col in dfr.columns if col.startswith(prefix)]
    for col in coltocal:
        dfr.loc[:,col+'_new'] = dfr.price*dfr[col]
dfr

    Brand   price   S_Value S_Factor    S_Value_new S_Factor_new
0   A   10  2   2   20  20
1   B   20  4   1   80  20
2   C   30  2   1   60  30
3   D   40  1   2   40  80
4   E   50  1   1   50  50
5   F   10  1   1   10  10
```

Just add as many prefixes you have to `pre_fixes` (use come to separate them)