Pandas dataframe get location of col if name contains string and slice into multiple dataframes
I am reading a .csv that has multiple time series columns, but each has a different name based on packets. My goal is to find the col names that contain the string 'TIME' and get their col numbers so that I can slice the df into multiple dfs with cols beginning with the time series col and ending before the next time series col.
I can get a list of the col names but I am not being able to get their locs in the original df:
time_cols = [col for col in df.columns if 'TIME' in col]
time_cols_loc = df.columns.get_loc(time_cols)

The above gives an InvalidIndexError, I am assuming because it is extracting that list instead of finding the values in the original df. I am also not sure how to slice it afterwards.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20903553

get_loc  does not accept a list as a parameter. Using your approach it would have to be:  time_cols_loc = [df.columns.get_loc(c) for c in time_cols]. But, the link @BigBen sent shows a better solution.

As the comments explain, get_loc does not accept a list as a parameter.
Use a list comprehension instead:
time_col_indices = [df.columns.get_loc(col) for col in time_cols]

print("Columns containing 'TIME':", time_cols)
print("Column indices:", time_col_indices)

Output:
Columns containing 'TIME': ['TIME_Column1', 'TIME_Column2']
Column indices: [0, 1]


You don't need to get the columns' locs. You can just do slicing with their column names.
for example:
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'PACKET1_TIME': [1, 2, 3],
    'DATA1': [4, 5, 6],
    'DATA2': [7, 8, 9],
    'PACKET2_TIME': [10, 11, 12],
    'DATA3': [13, 14, 15],
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

time_cols = [col for col in df.columns if 'TIME' in col]

sliced_df = df.loc[:,time_cols[0]:time_cols[1]]

print(sliced_df)

-> sliced_df
   PACKET1_TIME  DATA1  DATA2  PACKET2_TIME
0             1      4      7            10
1             2      5      8            11
2             3      6      9            12


First of all, you can fix your code as follows to make it work:
time_cols_loc = [x for x, col in enumerate(df.columns) if 'TIME' in col]

But I think you can do better with MultiIndex:
slices = df.columns.str.match('time').cumsum()
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([slices, df.columns], 
                                       names=['slice', df.columns.name or 'data'])

Now you can reach each slice by its number, like df[1] to get the first time slice, or df[0] to get everything that precedes the first time column if any, or [df[x] for x in df.columns.levels[0]] to get a list of all slices. To restore the previous columns, drop the column level with the slice numbers like df.droplevel('slice', 'columns') or df.droplevel(0, axis=1).
Code for experiments:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

columns = ['some', 'thing', 'time1', 'data1', 'data2', 
           'time2', 'time3', 'data3', 'data4']
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(5*len(columns)).reshape(5, -1, order='F'), columns=columns)

print('Original data:', '-'*20, df, '', sep='\n')

slices = df.columns.str.match('time').cumsum()    
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([slices, df.columns], 
                                       names=['slice', df.columns.name or 'data'])
for x in df.columns.levels[0]:
    print(f'Slice {x}:', '-'*20, df[x], '', sep='\n')

Original data:
--------------------
   some  thing  time1  data1  data2  time2  time3  data3  data4
0     0      5     10     15     20     25     30     35     40
1     1      6     11     16     21     26     31     36     41
2     2      7     12     17     22     27     32     37     42
3     3      8     13     18     23     28     33     38     43
4     4      9     14     19     24     29     34     39     44

Slice 0:
--------------------
data  some  thing
0        0      5
1        1      6
2        2      7
3        3      8
4        4      9

Slice 1:
--------------------
data  time1  data1  data2
0        10     15     20
1        11     16     21
2        12     17     22
3        13     18     23
4        14     19     24

Slice 2:
--------------------
data  time2
0        25
1        26
2        27
3        28
4        29

Slice 3:
--------------------
data  time3  data3  data4
0        30     35     40
1        31     36     41
2        32     37     42
3        33     38     43
4        34     39     44

